# Windows Azure TFS build definition 'Copy build output...' #/ issue

Tags: .net, azure

I have created account on online TFS* and made build configuration on Azure. But the default build definition creation on TFS is Continuous Integration*. However, I want to make on Schedule like daily at some time (8.00 am).

But it says

```
TFS42069: The path '#/' is not a valid UNC path. A UNC path must be of the format \\server\share
```

Can anyone tell what should there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this blogpost on how to resolve this issue :-) http://techmike2kx.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/tfs-preview-error403-and-windowsazure-continuous-integrationdelivery/